# Simplification of Hankel functions

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

I have this Hankel function, $H_{1}(R_{1}+R_{2})e^{i\cos(a)}$. Would it be possible to simplify this function in terms of $H_{1}(R_{1})$ and $H_{1}(R_{2})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists an [addition formula for Bessel functions](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_363.htm) due to Graf. In the case you are interested in this addition formula takes the form
$$H^{(1)}_{\nu}\left(R_1+R_2\right)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}H^{(1)}_{\nu-k}\left(R_1\right)J_k\left(R_2\right),$$
where it is assumed that $|R_2|<|R_1|$. I'm not sure whether this can be called a simplification, but there seems to be no way to get anything more compact.

Comment: Weierstrass showed that $J_\nu(R_1 + R_2)$ cannot be expressed as an algebraic function of $J_\nu(R_1)$ and $J_\nu(R_2)$. See p358 in https://books.google.com/books?id=Mlk3FrNoEVoC&pg=PA358&dq=Weierstrass+addition+formula+Watson&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAmoVChMIre2Ts8aexwIVgl2SCh0TqwGe#v=onepage&q=Weierstrass%20addition%20formula%20Watson&f=false.Therefore, I do not believe one can simplify Graf's addition formula.  From a numerical point of view, if |R_2| is small, then Graf's formula can be severely truncated. (This is the basis for some nonuniform Hankel transform algorithms.)